# how to ensure no memory leak in the following case

Tags: c#, .net

If a class has a property which contains unmanaged  resources. How to make sure no memory leak when using the class

```
Class A
{
         B {get; set;}
}
```

B contains unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Implement `IDisposable` and clean up your unmanaged resources by calling `Dispose()`, preferably placing the call to `Dispose` in a `finally` statement so you clean up resources even in the case of an exception.

C# has a `using` keyword that you can employ to make sure that the `Dispose` method is called, even if an exception is thrown.

**EDIT: Incorporated call to GC.SuppressFinalize and finalizer implementation per Ran's answer**

```
class A : IDisposable
{
    private bool _disposed;

    ~A()
    {
        this.Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        this.Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!_disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                // dispose managed resources
            }

            // clean up unmanaged resources

            _disposed = true;
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var someInstance = new A())
        {
            // do some things with the class.
            // once the using block completes, Dispose
            // someInstance.Dispose() will automatically
            // be called
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think a Finalizer is needed in OP's situation. See my answer for more details....

Answer (score 4):

Using `IDisposable` might not be enough, because it relies on the user remembering to call `Dispose` or to use `using` etc.

For a complete solution, combine `IDisposable` and a finalizer. Like this:

**Edit:** Made some corrections in the Dispose method based on **SpeksETC**'s comment.

```
class MyClass : IDisposable
{
    ~MyClass() 
    {
        Dispose(false);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        GC.SupressFinalize();
        Dispose(true);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposing)
        {
            // clear unmanaged resources here (can only be called once)
            ...
        }

        // dispose called explicitly by the user, clean up managed resources here
        ...
    }
}
```

This ensures that native resources will always be cleared, even if the user forgets to call `Dispose`, while still allowing the user to clear the resources early.

The `if` inside the `Dispose` implementation is needed because if this class is being finalized, you may not call `Dispose` on your members because they may have been GC'ed already.

Comment: +1: Good job tying in the finalizer as well.  For some reason, I had thought that Microsoft began discouraging the practice.

Comment: Finalizers do have a performance penalty, but I think it applies only if the finalizers are actually called (because of the overhead of the GC managing the finalizable queue etc). So, in your own application, you should always Dispose of objects if you can. However, when writing a library you may want to protect your users who may neglect to call Dispose. For them, the performance hit would be better than a memory leak...

Comment: "you should always Dispose of objects" - completely agree, and would even consider a Finalizer being called as a bug. To prevent these bugs, I would suggest adding a Debug.Assert to finalizers to easily catch them...

Comment: Wouldn't b.Dispose() go within the if condition you mentioned since it is managed and could already be GC'd when A is being finalized? I don't think a finalizer is needed in this case, see my answer....

Comment: @SpecksETC, adding a Debug.Assert to your finalizer depends on your requirements. If you're writing a library I would advise against it because you would probably prefer that your less-skilled users still be able to use the class even if they don't call Dispose.

Comment: @SpeksETC, your second comment is correct, I should have inverted the if to ensure that unmanaged resources are freed only in the case of Finalizer, which can only be called once, and not on Dispose which can be called multiple times.

Comment: @Ran, re:Debug.Assert, I agree it depends on your requirements, but even when you write a library you can still deploy a release build to users and they won't be affected by your Debug.Assert.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is important to point out that B is a **managed** resource that only **contains** unmanaged resources.

Therefore, A should implement IDisposable and dispose of B in its Dispose() method, but does not need a finalizer since it doesn't have any unmanaged resources to clean up - the finalizer needs to be implemented within B itself. Even if you implemented a finalizer it would call a Dispose that  looked like this:

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing) 
    { 
        if (disposing) 
        { 
            // dispose called explicitly by the user, clean up managed resources here 
            b.Dispose() 
        } 

        // no unmanaged resources to clean up so do nothing which makes Finalizer unneccesary
        ... 
    }
```

Comment: That's right. The class that has the unmanaged resources is the one that should clear them. In my example, the MyClass class is actually B, and A only has to dispose of B because A doesn't really have any unmanaged resources.

Answer (score 0):

SpeksEtc is correct in that if B contains unmanaged resources then B should ensure there are no leaks not A.

But what are the unmanaged resources and would the [SafeHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.safehandle.aspx) class help? Then B would contain a SafeHandle which would contain the unmanaged resource and you wouldn't need to worry about it.